# What are the maximum levels in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I would like to know, what is the maximum level in Fallout Shelter for a:

- Dweller's main level.
- Specific SPECIAL stat (excluding clothing bonuses).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your dwellers can level up until Level 50. Each level of your dweller will increase their health points.

The S.P.E.C.I.A.L. stats will be capped at 10 for training. If you reach a value of 10 at a S.P.E.C.I.A.L. attribute you won't be able to train the dweller further in this stat. Instead of further training, you are able to give them better cloths which can raise their S.P.E.C.I.A.L. attributes further. A good tactic is to train your dwellers in their main stat until 10 and probably their Luck too (as it will increase your rush-chance). After that you can provide a Luck-based or a working specific outfit to your dweller.

Comment: Stats are capped at 10, but clothes can boost them even further. Also, the amount of useful stat depends on your playstyle. For someone who fires up the game, harvest everything and then leave for long time, powerplant worker with 1 STR is as good as one with 10.

Comment: Can you elaborate? If you use a person with S10 + military on a reactor, the info on the tooltip just display +10 not +13 (as it should with a military outfit)

Comment: Reactor with one 12 STR  and one 2 STR guys takes same time to finish production as when there are 2x 7 STR guys. And their stats matter only for time to complete (and rush chance), produced amount is constant.

Comment: I've tested it before with my reactor guys as I've had a S:10+3 and a S:10 + a S:3 guy. The S:10 + S:3 guys are faster in my game?

Comment: There may be a cap on the room as a whole, e.g. size 3 reactor caps at 60str. I'm not sure, I don't have enough stats to max out a room, just barely enough to go over 10 on one or 2 guys.

Comment: I've tested it to max it. Yes your right. It seems to work. But at some point it stops working. There seems to be a cap at some point. But at this point the room had a production time from about  ~30 seks. I edit the answer.

Answer (score 7):

[image]
[image]

I am pretty sure a Dwellers main level caps out at 50.  I have Sarah Lyons at 50, and her bar is full, didn't move into level 51 after 2 days in the wasteland.. lol.

They are right!  the S.P.E.C.I.A.L attributed of all vault dwellers caps out at 10, but you can raise it above the cap with the clothes.

Answer (score 0):

One of my dwellers, colonel autumn is currently at 67, so I know they go higher than 50

Comment: Please answer with exact values, or comment this.

Comment: How can they go higher than 50? That contradicts what everybody else is saying.

Comment: Need a screenshot.  I haven't heard they raised the cap yet.